# Using a struct to make a table of data types

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to make a table using structs, with the struct containing a char array, and boolean. Any advice as to what is wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
""
static const char bar[] = "bar";
static const char foo[] = "foo";

struct listType
   {
       const char Value[];
       bool successValue;
   };


listType test
{
    {foo , false},
    {bar , false}
};
""
```

The idea is that I would be able to set the variables to true down the line.

Unfortunately I am getting a too many initializers as well as braces around scalar initializers errors. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Arrays *must* have a size so your structure declaration is invalid. You can use pointers to point to the strings. Or even better (much *much* better) use `std::string` for all your strings.

Comment: Yes, use `std::string` . It gives much more flexibility and freedom.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a constructor without declaring one. Instead, assign each value individually. Like,

```
listType test[2];
test[0].Value = foo;
test[0].successValue = false;
test[1].Value = bar;
test[1].successValue = false;
```

Note, the string assignment only works for `std::string` type variable. For character array, you have to use strcpy() function. So,

```
test[0].Value = foo;
```

Would be,

```
strcpy(test[0].Value, foo);
```